# What is this strange circular design between shutter and EV compensation button on the Nikon D3300?

Tags: camera-controls, nikon-d3300

[image]

I found a strange circular design on my Nikon D3300. I could not find this referenced in the manual. What does this signify?

Answer (score 28):

On page 1 of the[*Nikon D3300 reference manual*](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/E7vrv00ZwHJt02sHgtZ15XIHOb30/D3300RM_(En)03.pdf) the [+/-] button pictured to the lower left in the image included in the question is listed as the:

[image]

When shooting in manual exposure mode with Nikon cameras that have only a single control wheel, such as your D3300, the wheel - which is labeled the 'command dial' in your user's manual - controls the shutter speed setting . To control the aperture setting you need to press and hold down the exposure compensation button (the button with the [+/-] on it) while turning the control wheel. **The 'circular design' is supposed to look like a lens' aperture iris and is placed next to the [+/-] button because it is additional labeling for the [+/-] button.**

[image]

It's on page 109 of the [*Nikon D3300 Reference Manual*](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/E7vrv00ZwHJt02sHgtZ15XIHOb30/D3300RM_(En)03.pdf).